# JSON field no data, or unable to get the appropriate data

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I'm doing this code for my android programming school project and I've come into a problem which it seems that the JSON has an error in retrieving some of the data from the API it was to take from.

This is an water intake app I'm working on and I'm using the free API provided by openweathermap.org while referencing the code from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android--cms-21587 . The difference is that instead of using a activity and a fragment, I've combined the fragment and activity together with minor modifications to make it runnable on Eclipse.

Here's my code where it goes wrong:

```
private void updateWeatherInfo(final String city) {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                final JSONObject json = FetchData.getJSON(MainActivity.this, city);
                if(json == null) {
                    handleWeather.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() { 
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.place_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    handleWeather.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            renderWeather(json);
                        }
                    });
                }

        }
    }.start();
}

private void renderWeather(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        cityData.setText(json.getString("name").toUpperCase(Locale.US) + ", " + json.getJSONObject("sys").getString("country"));

        JSONObject details = json.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject main = json.getJSONObject("main");
        detailsData.setText(details.getString("description").toUpperCase(Locale.US) + "\n" + "Humidity: " + main.getString("humidity") + "%" + "\n" + "Pressure: " + main.getString("pressure") + " hPa");

        currentTemperatureData.setText(String.format("%.2f", main.getDouble("temp"))+ " ℃");

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        String updatedOn = df.format(new Date(json.getLong("dt")*1000));
        updatedData.setText("Last update: " + updatedOn);

        getWeatherIcon(details.getInt("id"), json.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunrise") * 1000, json.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunset") * 1000);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("SimpleWeather", "One or more fields not found in the JSON data");
    }
}
```

The exception at the try/catch keeps one happening once it reaches cityData and detailsData. I know this because when I debugged it and reaching there it goes straight to the catch after a few step ins, and with commenting out the cityData the next time it got routed to the catch again was at detailsData.

Could anyone see what's wrong and help me point it out?

EDIT: here's the API im using - http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Singapore,sg

EDIT2: It seems it is because my `onCreateView` which initialises my textViews was after the `updateWeatherData` and I've since moved it first before the `updateWeatherData` was called. Now, however, I realise that my `onCreateView` has also no `@Override`, and upon putting in the `@Override` an error occurs that it must implement a supertype method.

The code is as such:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        cityData = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.city_field);
        updatedData = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.updated_field);
        detailsData = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.details_field);
        currentTemperatureData = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
        weatherIcon = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);

        weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherIcons);

        return rootView; 
    }
```

I understand that this code was meant for a fragment, but implementing it into an Activity it seems I have missed a step in modifying it here. How do I proceed from here?

EDIT3: I have now implemented the `onCreateView` data into the `onCreate` , since the `onCreateView` is the fragment version of `onCreate` . However, I have run into another problem that is out of this question's scope in that my `setTypeface` returns a NullPointerException. he code of which can be seen below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView cityData;
    TextView updatedData;
    TextView detailsData;
    TextView currentTemperatureData;
    TextView weatherIcon;
    Typeface weatherIcons;
    Handler handleWeather;

    public MainActivity() {
        handleWeather = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cityData = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.city_field);
        updatedData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_field);
        detailsData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details_field);
        currentTemperatureData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
        weatherIcon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);

        weatherIcons = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "weather.ttf"); 

        weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherIcons);
```

As such, I will continue my search to this problem for a while, and if I find my answer, I will not post up another question. However, I shall close this question as answered.

Comment: probably `cityData` and `detailsData` is null make sure you are initializing both variables before calling `updateWeatherInfo` method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: I've moved the initialisation upwards to before the `updateWeatherInfo` , but still the exception occurs at the same points.